React Native - Expo freezes while building android app
Due to a future mobile project and knowledge of react and typescript I wanted to get into react native. I followed the instructions as found on the official react native "get started" page and went on by using expo.
Unfortunately, when building the android app the process freezes without any further texts in the log (building the ios app works just fine).
After prebuilding the code I used npm run android and it freezes at the point as you see in the picture below.

I first noticed it when I tried to use a module which is not supported by expo go and also not by the ios simulations. The code I was trying to build here was just the Hello World boiler plate.
OS:
Mac Sonoma 14.5
IDE:
VS Code 3
Installed tools: React Native Tools v1.13.0; Expo Tools v1.5.0
Android Emulator:
Pixel 7, Android API 35
My package.json:
{
  "name": "test",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "~51.0.17",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.7",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.17",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.6",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

